Are there any conditions that do not allow a Module to register with ObjectMapper in Jackson?
I have the following super simple code to test the functionality of a custom serializer in Jackson. For some reason, the module does not register to the ObjectMapper (at least I don't see it register based on the results). Are there any conditions that do not allow a Module to register with ObjectMapper?
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

public class TestJacksonCustomSerializer {

    public class TheClass {

        public String emptyString = null;
        public String[] emptyStringArray= null;

        public TheClass() {
            
        }
        
        public String getEmptyString() {
            return emptyString;
        }
        
        public String[] getEmptyStringArray() {
            return emptyStringArray;
        }
    }
    
    public class NullStringJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(String string, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Processing value: " + String.valueOf(string));
            if (string == null) jsonGenerator.writeString("");          
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        TestJacksonCustomSerializer testJacksonCustomSerializer = new TestJacksonCustomSerializer();

        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(String.class, testJacksonCustomSerializer.new NullStringJsonSerializer());
        
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
        
        System.out.println("Number of registered modules: " + String.valueOf(objectMapper.getRegisteredModuleIds().size()));
    
        TheClass theClass = testJacksonCustomSerializer.new TheClass();
        
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(theClass));
        
    }
}

Output:
Number of registered modules: 0
{"emptyString":null,"emptyStringArray":null}

I am using jackson 2.12.7

BTW your serializer is incorrect. You have to always write some value.

Your serializer is not invoked because Jackson determine serializer by type of value, not by type of property. Your value is null so NullSeriaizer is used.

I see. So one way to do it is this:  public class NullJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer {
@Override
public void serialize(Object object, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
jsonGenerator.writeString("");
}
}............. objectMapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullValueSerializer(testJacksonCustomSerializer.new NullJsonSerializer());

Yes. If you want to turn all nulls into "".

Good point on the "all" nulls to "". I am wondering if there is a way to have different custom Null Serializers per type of property. I understand Null is Null no matter the property type but if there is a need to handle those differently, is JsonSerializer still the way to go? For example, replace a property of type String with value Null with "", but replace a property of type String[] with value Null with "[]"

No. It is impossible to do what you want by configuring ObjectMapper unless you ready to create your own implementation of BeanSerializer (not advisable, it is huge). You can solve it easily by annotating all properties :)
